# CouchDB request with JWT causes error "No DB shards could be opened"

Tags: http, authentication, jwt, couchdb

I have a couchdb server, which at this moment is for development and it has just one node running in docker.

I would like to authenticate through JWT.  I have build my token.

```
GET https://comp010:6984/_session
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer <JWT token>
```

I get proper answer (or at least I think so):

```json
{
  "ok": true,
  "userCtx": {
    "name": "uaru",
    "roles": "admin"
  },
  "info": {
    "authentication_handlers": [
      "jwt",
      "cookie",
      "default"
    ],
    "authenticated": "jwt"
  }
}
```

When I send request to get actual object from the database

```
GET https://comp010:6984/db_userspaces/xxxx3
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I get "unauthorized" exception. This is ok, I did not authenticated this request. So I add the same authorization header:

```
GET https://comp010:6984/db_userspaces/xxxx3
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer <JWT token>
```

And I get

```json
{
  "error": "internal_server_error",
  "reason": "No DB shards could be opened.",
  "ref": 179462285
}
```

But if I switch off the authorization ( [chttpd] require_valid_user = false), and send the same request without Authorization header,

```
GET https://comp010:6984/db_userspaces/xxxx3
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I get proper response.

```json
Server: CouchDB/3.2.1 (Erlang OTP/23)
X-Couch-Request-ID: 02c628ce15
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0

{
  "_id": "xxxx3",
  "_rev": "1-a11f390ffa77a03c557ffbbc7c5fda75",
  "x": "1"
}
```

How JWT can relate to shards? I am puzzled and I cannot find anything related.

There are no errors with Fauxton.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Here is the log when the request took place

```
couchdb-server_1  | [error] 2022-03-09T04:52:34.662593Z nonode@nohost <0.6234.1> 82a6b79f38 rexi_server: from: nonode@nohost(<0.6134.1>) mfa: fabric_rpc:open_shard/2 error:function_clause [{lists,usort,[<<"admin">>],[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1063}]},{couch_db,check_security,3,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,713}]},{couch_db,is_authorized,2,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,705}]},{couch_db,is_member,1,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,685}]},{couch_db,check_is_member,1,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,671}]},{couch_db,open,2,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,166}]},{mem3_util,get_or_create_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_util.erl"},{line,549}]},{fabric_rpc,open_shard,2,[{file,"src/fabric_rpc.erl"},{line,307}]}]
couchdb-server_1  | [error] 2022-03-09T04:52:34.662982Z nonode@nohost <0.6236.1> 82a6b79f38 rexi_server: from: nonode@nohost(<0.6134.1>) mfa: fabric_rpc:open_shard/2 error:function_clause [{lists,usort,[<<"admin">>],[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1063}]},{couch_db,check_security,3,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,713}]},{couch_db,is_authorized,2,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,705}]},{couch_db,is_member,1,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,685}]},{couch_db,check_is_member,1,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,671}]},{couch_db,open,2,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,166}]},{mem3_util,get_or_create_db,2,[{file,"src/mem3_util.erl"},{line,549}]},{fabric_rpc,open_shard,2,[{file,"src/fabric_rpc.erl"},{line,307}]}]
couchdb-server_1  | [error] 2022-03-09T04:52:34.663440Z nonode@nohost <0.6134.1> 82a6b79f38 req_err(179462285) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
couchdb-server_1  |     [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L118">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L132">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L183">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L112">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>,<<"chttpd:handle_req_after_auth/2 L325">>,<<"chttpd:process_request/1 L310">>,<<"chttpd:handle_request_int/1 L249">>]
couchdb-server_1  | [notice] 2022-03-09T04:52:34.663753Z nonode@nohost <0.6134.1> 82a6b79f38 comp010:6984 ::ffff:150.26.121.46 uaru GET /db_userspaces/xxxx3 500 ok 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the payload to be turned into JWT, `roles` MUST BE an array.

```
{
   :sub => username,
   :'_couchdb.roles' => roles,
   :exp => ...,
}
```

In my case, `roles` was not. But it means that should be error `400 Bad Request`.

The whole problem has nothing to do with shards configuration, etc. The error message was misleading.

Thanks to people in CouchDb slack channel for guiding me in the right direction.